# Microsoft Power BI DAX - tricky situation using ALLEXCEPT

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a situation in which I have a single excel file with one sheet, I am loading this single sheet (Sales) as a Power BI table.

I have two major dimension columns - Model and Product. I have a single numerical column called SalesAmount.

In all there are just 3 source columns in my Sales table.

One Model can have many Products, hence a 1:M relationship, but in the same (Sales) table.

I am using a Power BI matrix, as shown.

[image]

I have the following:

1)

Measure called **[Sum of SalesAmount]**: a simple sum of the SamesAmount column

2)

A Calculated Column called **[ModelSalesAmount]** in the Sales table:

```
ModelSalesAmount = CALCULATE(
                             SUM(Sales[SalesAmount]),
                             ALLEXCEPT(Sales,Sales[Model])
                            )
```

3. 

A Calculated Column called **[ProductOnModel]** in the Sales table:

```
ProductOnModel = Sales[SalesAmount]/Sales[ModelSalesAmount]
```

I have the matrix visual as shown.

The aggregated value for the ModelSalesAmount is incorrect.

HL Fountain Frame is a Model, and there are 8 products under this Model.

The Calculated column Sales[ModelSalesAmount] with a SUM aggregation in the matrix, works correctly at the product level (3,365,069.274), but not at the Model level. The Model level aggregation 26,920,554.19 is incorrect. I would want 3,365,069.274 at the Model level, NOT 26,920,554.19.

Interestingly, the Calculated Column Sales[ProductOnModel] with a SUM aggregation in the matrix, while using the Sales[ModelSalesAmount] Calculated Column in the denominator works correctly, both at the individual product level, as well as at the Model level!

What should I do to remove the undesired value 26,920,554.19, and make it 3,365,069.274 ?

I tried this below, but not working:

```
ModelSalesAmount_CC =  IF (

                            HASONEVALUE(Sales[Product]) = TRUE,
                            
                            CALCULATE(

                                      SUM(Sales[SalesAmount]),

                                      ALLEXCEPT(Sales,Sales[Model])

                                     ),

                             ...........

                           )
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: I'd recommend making ModelSalesAmount a measure instead of a calculated column that you create an implicit (sum) measure on top of to put in a visual.

Comment: @AlexisOlson    Thanks Alexis, I will try and get back later today

Answer (score 0):

Change the Calculated Column [ModelSalesAmount] to a measure, I get the right output. Thanks Alexis.